# Access TextField value from another composable function in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have created two `TextField` Email, Password & `Button` Login. Now on click of that button I want to access text and show success/error based on validation.

The problem is they are in two different composable functions.

```
@Composable
    fun EmailField() {
        var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.White,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                focusedLabelColor = Color.White
            ),
            value = email,
            onValueChange = { email = it },
            label = { Text("Email") },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Email,
                    "contentDescription",
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {})
            }
        )
    }
```

Button:

```
@Composable
    private fun LoginButton() {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                      // validate email and password here
            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                contentColor = Color.White
            )
        ) {
            Text(text = "Login")
        }
    }
```

If you want to see whole activity this is how it's structured at the moment.

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                    LoginLogo()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "Login",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
                    Text(
                        text = "Please sign in to continue",
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(32.dp))
                    EmailField()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    PassWordField()
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
                    LoginButton()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun LoginButton() {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                      // validate email and password here
            },
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = Color.Yellow,
                contentColor = Color.White
            )
        ) {
            Text(text = "Login")
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun LoginLogo() {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_vector_app_logo),
            contentDescription = "Login Logo",
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(120.dp)
                .height(120.dp)
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun EmailField() {
        var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.White,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                focusedLabelColor = Color.White
            ),
            value = email,
            onValueChange = { email = it },
            label = { Text("Email") },
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Email,
                    "contentDescription",
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {})
            }
        )
    }

    @Composable
    fun PassWordField() {
        var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.9f),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.White,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.White,
                focusedLabelColor = Color.White
            ),
            value = password,
            onValueChange = { password = it },
            label = { Text("Password") },
            visualTransformation = PasswordVisualTransformation(),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Password),
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(
                    Icons.Filled.Lock,
                    "contentDescription",
                    modifier = Modifier.clickable {})
            }
        )
    }


}
```

What is the right way to handle values in this case?

Comment: You can use `ViewModel` architecture component to manage these fields and the state changes. [Read](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `ViewModel` or something like:

```
class TextFieldState(){
    var text: String by mutableStateOf("")
}

@Composable
fun login(){

    var emailState = remember { TextFieldState() }

    EmailField(emailState)
    LoginButton( onValidate = { /** validate **/})

}
```

with:

```
@Composable
fun EmailField( emailState : TextFieldState = remember { TextFieldState() }) {

    TextField(
        value = emailState.text,
        onValueChange = {
            emailState.text = it
        },
        //your code
   )
}
```

and:

```
@Composable
private fun LoginButton(onValidate: () -> Unit) {
    Button(
        onClick =  onValidate,
        //your code
    )
}
```

Comment: This would cause recomposition on every input word?

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution with **rememberSaveable**

```
@Composable
fun MainBody() {
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .fillMaxWidth()
) {
    var inputValue by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    CommonTextField(value = inputValue, onInputChanged = { inputValue = it })
}
}
```

And here it is defined CommonTextField Function

```
 @Composable
 fun CommonTextField(value: String, onInputChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
 TextField(value = value,
    onValueChange = onInputChanged,
 modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .padding(16.dp),
label = { Text(text = "Enter here")})
}
```

Comment: { inputValue = it } // You cannot reassign value to a val

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this with the following way :-

```
@Composable
fun login(){
    var dataInput = "xyz@abc.com"
    EmailField(dataInput, onChange = { dataInput = it })
    LoginButton( onValidate = { /** validate **/})
}

@Composable
fun EmailField(textData: String, onChange: (String) -> Unit = {}) {
   var textInput by remember { mutableStateOf(textData) }    
   TextField(
       value = textInput,
       onValueChange = {
          textInput = it
          onChange(it)
       },
                //your code
     )
}
```

The beauty of this is that it will ***not*** recompose all the other views again on changing input for any TextField.

Comment: After any login() recomposition dataInput value change to declared ("xyz@abc.com")