# how can one composable change other composable value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have textField composable and button composable. I want that clicking at the button would erase the text in the textField composable.

example:

```
var text by remember 
mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))}

TextField(
  value = text,
  onValueChange = { newValue -> text = newValue },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(8.dp),
                    )

Button(
 onClick = { 
                //TODO: clean the text in textFiled
                      },
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(200.dp, 40.dp)
            
        ) {
            Text(text = "erase textField"
        }
```

thanks

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217106/access-textfield-value-from-another-composable-function-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 1):

- Create a mutableState as follows -> `var textState by remember { mutableStateOf("") }`
- Create Textfield -> `TextField(value = textState, onValueChange = { textState = it })`
- In the onClick of the button invoke the textState -> `textState = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply reset the value of the text `mutableState`:

```
Button(onClick = { text = TextFieldValue("") })
```

Comment: but it is not what I want. It's question for change data between composables. not just clean the data, more changes. Anyway, I think I know the solution but the stackoverflow rules can't let me write it.